# Ionic 5 android Not remove scroll bounce effect

Tags: android, ionic-framework, scroll

I have a problem in Ionic 5 with scrolls in android. I can't find a way to disable the scroll bounce effect and it's not usable.

When you release your finger or reach the end of the list it bounces to the beginning, you cannot navigate normally.

```
 Ionic CLI                       : 6.11.10 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

 NodeJS : v12.19.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.8
```

```
<ion-content class="card-background-page" (animationiteration)="false" [forceOverscroll]="false" [scrollEvents]="false" scroll-y="false">
    <ion-virtual-scroll (animationiteration)="false"  class="list-species" [items]="levels" approxItemHeight="200px">
        <ion-card *virtualItem="let level; let itemBounds = bounds;" (click)="levelClicked(level)">
            <ion-img *ngIf="level.img != null" [src]="apiUrl + '/uploads/species/' + level.img" alt=""></ion-img>
            <div class="card-title">{{level.label}}</div>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was causing the problem. I have removed from the AndroidManifest.xml the option
"android: hardwareAccelerated =" false "

and the problem has been fixed.